# How does pip know which Wheel to grab to work with your system?

Tags: pip, python-wheel

If a Python Wheel contains pre-compiled code for the dependencies, how does `pip` decide or know which wheel to grab because compiled code can have problems such as only working for the OS/CPU architecture it was compiled on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filename of a wheel specifies which platforms it is compatible with, and `pip` is able to check the platform of the machine it is running on, so it uses that information to figure out which wheels can be used. You can find more information about it [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-format).